# Как реализовать логику решения задачи с тензорами без циклов (срезами)

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

**Постановка задачи**

Имеется mapper - вспомогательная структура для заполнения массива `modificated_arr` значениями из `condition1` и `condition2`. Маппер это двумерный массив (одинаковой размерности с `modifacted_arr`) заполненный списками из двух элементов, где первый указывает на индекс массива из conditions, а второй - какой именно массив (`condition1` или `condition2`)/ Например элемент `[3, 0]` - означает, что по индексам 0, 1 массива `modificated_arr` - нужно установить значение 4 элемента из `condition1`.Решение задачи простое - проитерироваться по `mapper`-у, считать данные и заполнить массив `modicated_arr` этими значениями. 
Проблема заключается в том, что надо это сделать для тензоров без итераций, то есть назначать значения сразу срезам массива `modificated_arr`. Типа такого `modificated_arr[:,:] = mappper[slice1,slice2,slice3]`

Каждая из переменных ниже представляет собой тензор torch, но думаю решение numpy массивов не сильно будет отличаться. Поэтому добавлен тег `numpy`

```
mapper = torch.tensor([
          [[0,0],[3, 0], [4, 1]],
          [[2,1],[4, 0], [3, 1]]
         ])

condition1 = torch.tensor([0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
condition2 = torch.tensor([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])

modificated_arr = torch.tensor([
                   [0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0]
                  ])
```

Решение с циклами:

```
for row_idx, row in enumerate(mapper):
    for col_idx, col in enumerate(row):

        cond_idx, cond = col

        if cond == 0:
            modificated_arr[row_idx, col_idx] = condition1[cond_idx]

        else:
            modificated_arr[row_idx, col_idx] = condition2[cond_idx]
```

Дополнения к объяснению:

Первые два измерения mapper-а соответствуют измерениям modificated_arr. То есть
mapper[1,2] должен будет изменить элемент массива modificated_arr[1,2] следующим образом. mapper[1,2] это массив [3,1]. Первый элемент двумерного массива означает номер индекса condition1 или condition2, второй элемент - 1 отвечает какой из condition - ов брать, он соответствует condtion2 то есть нужно будет изменить modificated_arr[1,2] = cond2[3].

Comment: Во-первых `mapper` это 3D тензор размерности `(2, 3, 2)`, а `modifacted_arr` - 2D тензор размерности `(2, 3)` и утверждение в вопросе - `Маппер это двумерный массив (одинаковой размерности с modifacted_arr)` - неверно. Во-вторых, даже перечитав 3 раза `"заполненный списками из двух элементов, где первый указывает на индекс массива из conditions, а второй - какой именно массив (condition1 или condition2)/ Например элемент [3, 0] - означает, что по индексам 0, 1 массива modificated_arr - нужно установить значение 4 элемента из condition1"` - совершенно непонятно, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: Действительно, mapper это массив размерности (2,3,2). Элемент второго измерения представляет из себя массив из двух чисел. Который является руководящей информацией для выбора соответствующего элемента из condition1 или condition2. Понятно объяснил?

Comment: а что есть `Элемент второго измерения` ?

Comment: Можете расписать свой пример с `элемент [3, 0]` подробнее и понятнее? За что отвечает `mapper[0]`? Что означает `mapper[0, 1]` для указанного примера?

Comment: Элементами второго измерения - [0,0], [3,0],[4,1],...

Comment: mapper[0] - это маппер для первой строки modificated_arr, согласно ему надо будет изменить modificated_arr следующим образом `[cond1[0], cond1[3], cond2[4]]`,

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109233/discussion-between---and-maxu).

Answer (score 0):

Решение можно осуществить с булевыми масками.

```
modificated_arr[mapper[:, :, 1] == 0] += condition1[mapper[:, :, 0]][mapper[:, :, 1] == 0]
modificated_arr[mapper[:, :, 1] == 1] += condition2[mapper[:, :, 0]][mapper[:, :, 1] == 1]
```

Получаем ожидаемый результат:

```
modificated_arr
Out[6]: 
tensor([[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]])
```